# Palabras juntas si no pongo espacio

Tags: java-ee

Hola soy un estudiante que acaba de empezar y estoy haciendo una tarea, tengo un problema con este código

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio11 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre");
        String nombre_usuario=entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce tu primer apellido");
        String apellido1_usuario=entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce tu segundo apellido");
        String apellido2_usuario=entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("tu nombre es: " + nombre_usuario );
        System.out.println("tu primer apellido es: " + apellido1_usuario );
        System.out.println("tu segundo apellido  es: " + apellido2_usuario );

    }

}
```

El problema es que cuando le doy a Iniciar  a la consola con el Eclipse, cuando me pide mi nombre debo   por ejemplo Francisco( y añadirle un espacio) para que luego no se me junten con los demás datos en los otros 3 datos también debo poner el espacio.

¿Cual seria la solución para no tener que hacer eso? Supongo que será algún error de mí código.

Gracias

Comment: No acabo de entenderte. He probado el programa e imprime bien los datos que se introducen, cada uno en una línea, eso sí. ¿Los quieres juntos en la misma línea?

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, estarías necesitando agregar espacios a tus títulos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre : ");
   String nombre_usuario=entrada.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Introduce tu primer apellido : ");
   String apellido1_usuario=entrada.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Introduce tu segundo apellido : ");
   String apellido2_usuario=entrada.nextLine();

   System.out.println("tu nombre es: " + nombre_usuario );
   System.out.println("tu primer apellido es: " + apellido1_usuario );
   System.out.println("tu segundo apellido  es: " + apellido2_usuario );
```

}

Por otra parte te dejo otra librería más actualizada con la que puedes leer datos desde consola que fue introducido en java 1.6:

```
Console console = System.console();
if (console == null) {
   System.out.println("Sin consola interactiva!");
   System.exit(0);
}

   System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre : ");
   console.readLine();

   //Aqui ya se introduce el titulo y se solicita ingreso de datos al usuario
   console.readLine("Introduce tu primer apellido : "); 
}
```

Espero que te sirva.